# How to activate a wookbook named in a different module

Tags: excel, vba

I call module2 from module1 where I name a workbook "x" in module2. But later when I try "x.Activate" in module1 I get an error "Run-time error '424': Object required"

I have a rather lengthy module that I would like to organize by breaking it up into multiple modules. So far I have created a module called "INPUTS" in this module I have a "Sub RT_CMM_DATA_COMPILER_INPUTS()" presumably in the future I will have other Subs in this module "Sub RT_Some_Other_Project_INPUTS()" I name a workbook in "Sub RT_CMM_DATA_COMPILER_INPUTS()" and try to activate that workbook by name in a separate module called sandbox. But it displays an error.

```
'RT_Sandbox Module
Sub sandbox()

    Call RT_CMM_DATA_COMPILER_INPUTS

    wkbwatchFolders_table.Activate
    lastShtRow = LASTSHEETROW(ActiveSheet)

    MsgBox lastShtRow

End Sub


'Inputs module
Sub RT_CMM_DATA_COMPILER_INPUTS()

    watchFolders_filePath = "D:\RT_CMM_Data_File_Paths.xlsx"
    Set wkbwatchFolders_table = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=watchFolders_filePath)

End Sub
```

Am I going about this attempt to organize my code completely wrong? Should I be using class modules for this instead? Or is it just some syntax I am missing?

Comment: To make a object available in all procedures you need to declare it publicly. You can read more about it here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/declaring-variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The critical part you're missing is `Option Explicit` at the top of every module.

With that option, code will refuse to compile until all variables are explicitly declared.

Without it, `watchFolders_filePath` is an undeclared variable *in both  procedures*, and in the scope where it is read but not assigned, its data type is `Variant/Empty`.

[Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com/) (free, open-source VBIDE add-in project that I manage) can help locate and fix these issues (and others) in your code:

- [OptionExplicit](http://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/OptionExplicit) inspection
- [UnassignedVariableUsage](http://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/UnassignedVariableUsage) inspection
- [UndeclaredVariable](http://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/UndeclaredVariable) inspection
- [VariableNotAssigned](http://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/VariableNotAssigned) inspection
- [VariableNotUsed](http://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/VariableNotUsed) inspection

---

As for your code, you don't need any global variables. **Avoid global variables whenever possible**. Use functions (and parameters) instead:

```
Function RT_CMM_DATA_COMPILER_INPUTS() As Workbook
    Dim watchFolders_filePath As String
    watchFolders_filePath = "D:\RT_CMM_Data_File_Paths.xlsx"
    Set RT_CMM_DATA_COMPILER_INPUTS = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=watchFolders_filePath)
End Function
```

```
Sub sandbox()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = RT_CMM_DATA_COMPILER_INPUTS    
    wb.Activate
    lastShtRow = LASTSHEETROW(wb.ActiveSheet)

    MsgBox lastShtRow

End Sub
```

Comment: I ended up using a variation of this. I actually have several files that I open. Some as read only, some have passwords. This particular instance was read only. So I made a function (3 lines): Line 1 = "Function OPEN_PATH_READ_ONLY(FilePath As String) As Workbook" Line 2 = "Set OPEN_PATH_READ_ONLY = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilePath, ReadOnly:=True, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True)"  Line 3 = "End Function" This way I can simply feed in whatever path into this generic function

Comment: You could have a `ByVal openReadOnly As Boolean` parameter and not need a second function.

Comment: Also, consider sticking to `PascalCase` instead of `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE`, for better readability. There's a reason everything in the standard library (and Excel's) is `PascalCase`...

Answer (score 0):

Using `Public` statement will work here:

```
Public x As Workbook 
Public your_var As Object
```

You need to declare these outside your procedure, at the top of the module. After declaring these you can access them anywhere in any module.

Read More here: [Declaring Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/declaring-variables)

Comment: Ok... Looks like I got it to work. I wasn't sure what "outside the module" meant. But I found "https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/variable-scope.html" as a good source to help me understand. However, I only used the "Public x As Workbook" not "Public your_var As Object." Can you provide some insight into this second piece? I ran across a snippet a few weeks ago related to making graphs in excel vba and the snippet declared something "As Object" I think something like Dim chrt As Object or something... I Googled for a while and could not really ever find the meaning/when to use "As Object"

Comment: That article is way over my head... :-(

Comment: @XCELLGUY what it means is that any member call you make against `Object` can only ever be resolved at run-time, i.e. it's "late-bound". Whenever possible, use a known interface (e.g. `Workbook`, `Worksheet`, `Range`, etc.) rather than working off `Object`. That way you get compile-time validation and the editor assists you as you write the code (intellisense, autocomplete, parameter quick-info). *Everything* around you is an object: `As Object` (or `As Variant`) could be *anything*, and you usually don't want that.

Comment: Thank you... That was helpful. Good to know that I should typically avoid using "As Object." I already knew to avoid using "As Variant." Although I just used "As Variant" for a dynamic array. Which as I understand is necessary. Can you give an example of a situation I might run into where "As Object" is necessary?